# Is this table in 3NF?

Tags: mysql, database, 3nf

I have created a database for a vet clinic.

I have a table called appointments, and this is what it contains.

```
appointment_id, patient_id, customer_id, staff_id, date_time
```

- Each customer (owner) has a patient (pet).
- An appointment is taken by one staff.

So is my table structure right? It's meant to be 3nf.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.

There is a transitive dependency between `appointments` and `patients`. Consider this update anomaly:

```
UPDATE appointments 
SET appointments.patient_id = 42
WHERE appointments.appointment_id = 1;
/* hey that's not my dog! 
 */
```

If patients and customers are one-to-one, store the patient ID on the customer's table and reference it with a join.

If they are one to many, store the customer ID on the patient table for each patient.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain in simple words,

Condition for **Third normal form**:

> -It is in second normal form
>
> -There is no transitive functional dependency

In this relation,consider

> appointment_id as A
>
> patient_id as B
>
> customer_id as C

In your relation,
A->B

B->C
and A->C

Thus,there is a **transitive** functional dependency.

So,it is not in **3NF**.

Hope,it helps.